# How can I use AAR and RewriteModule to proxy AJAX requests?

Tags: rewrite, iis-7.5

Using IIS 7.5 with Advanced Application Routing.

I have setup a rewrite rule so that all requests to `http://server1/proxy/*` goto `http://server2:8080/*`

eg:

a request to `http://server1/proxy/authenticate` will be sent to `http://server2:8080/authenticate`

this does not work in all cases. For example, if I make a POST request using Javascript, then the request is rewritten to `http://server1/authenticate` which results in a 404.

However, using Firefox's REST client, making the same POST request with the same data, works fine.

So somehow AJAX requests are not being proxied, and I do not know why.

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console? It could be that your server doesn't accept cross-origin POST requests from javascript.

Comment: There are no cross origin POST requests since the reverse proxy hides this.